# Terminal Show Multiple Languages

Tags: 12.04, command-line, 12.10

At work, I need to connect to databases, and these database contain fields that hold Chinese, Russian, Spanish, Japanese, etc. characters. When pulling them up in my terminal, I get question marks. I know there is a way to show the actual characters instead of question marks, but how?

`:~$ locale` on the remote results in:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

`:~$ locale` on the clint results in:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check `locale` to make sure the server side is using UTF-8 or [change locale](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale) to UTF-8. Then configure your SSH client to use UTF-8 (not ISO-8859-1). For example, if using Putty, we have to set Putty's character set:

Putty: Window->Translation->Remote character set: UTF-8

[image]

Otherwise, it will use ISO-8859-1. A [Mac problem resolved](http://blog.remibergsma.com/2012/07/10/setting-locales-correctly-on-mac-osx-terminal-application/).

Alternatively, running this command while connected to a mysql database will output UTF-8 characters from mysql queries.

```
set character_set_results=utf8, character_set_client=utf8, character_set_connection=utf8;
```

Comment: So it is using UTF-8, and that doesn't work. so I ran these: `sudo cp /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local`
`sudo locale-gen` and that didn't work either.

Comment: @RyanNaddy Just type `locale`. If returns that it is using UTF-8, good! Now the client side must be configured to use UTF-8. Many do not do this without explicit configuration. What's your client?

Comment: They both are UTF-8. Please see updated question.

Comment: It does not matter that the client system is using UTF-8 with the  `locale` command. The SSH client itself probably needs to know to USE UTF-8. (Most need this.) Also: at a MySQL prompt: mysql> set character_set_results=utf8, character_set_client=utf8, character_set_connection=utf8;

Comment: this command fixed it: `set character_set_results=utf8, character_set_client=utf8, character_set_connection=utf8;`